# Shorten zipcode in email using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, formatting

The data extension I'm working with has a zipcode field that, for some people, populates the 5-digit zipcode and for others it has the additional 4 digits. Is there a way with ampscript that I can shorten to the 5-digit zipcode in the email? Or is there something I could do with sql to change that format?

Basically, we'd still like to have the extended zipcode in the data extension, but only want the 5-digit one in the email. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten NNNNN-NNNN using string manipulation and a bit of conditional logic to test whether we have at least the first five digits of the zip code:

```ampscript
%%[
    VAR @shortZip
    /* Check if we have a ZipCode to shorten */
    IF Length(ZipCode) >= 5 THEN 
        SET @shortZip = Substring(ZipCode,1,5)
    ELSE
        /* Do something here for empty/short ZipCodes */
        SET @shortZip = ZipCode
    ENDIF
]%%
ShortZip: %%=v(@shortZip)=%%
```